# How to solve the issue of 'Unable to connect to the server: EOF' Kubernetes failed to start

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am using Docker for Desktop with version 20.10.17. Whenever I try to enable Kubernetes v1.24.2 from Docker Desktop and then click on apply and restart, it shows **"Kubernetes failed to start"**. Moreover, when I type kubectl version in cmd, the version for client is shown but for server it displays **"Unable to connect to server: EOF"**. I have tried a number of solutions including purging  and resetting from troubleshooting option of docker desktop. I have disabled VPN, firewall but nothing is helping me. Can anyone help me overcome this problem?

Comment: do you see something here %APPDATA%\Local\Docker\log.txt

Comment: @jmvcollaborator Yes, a number of log.txt files.